# What is the process to get access of ChatGPT API?

Tags: python, flask, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm doing a mini project on generating synthetic data using ChatGPT in python for which I'm trying to get ChatGPT API access in flask framework but got stuck. Kindly guide me through the process.

I'm stuck at very beginning.

Comment: Pleas see [ask]. This is not a question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

First sign up as a developer and get an API key. They give you some demo tokens for your app's development but for further process you will need to request for a subscription.
Here is the detailed table:https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3-5
Please note that chatGPT is the same thing as GPT3.5 turbo. I used it before and they have a python package called `openai`.

```
import openai
openai.api_key = "sk-..."

# list models
models = openai.Model.list()

# print the first model's id
print(models.data[0].id)

# create a chat completion
chat_completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Hello world"}])

# print the chat completion
print(chat_completion.choices[0].message.content)
```

NOTE:Please don't forget that mentioned model costs $0.002 per 1k tokens.